# Where to find the output for the standalone

Tags: apache-flink

I have the following flink work count, when I run it in my IDE, it prints the word count correctly as follows

```
(hi,2)
(are,1)
(you,1)
(how,1)
```

But I when I run it in the cluster, I didn't find the output.

```
1. Start cluster using start-cluster.sh
2. Open the webui at http://localhost:8081
3. In the Submit new Job page, Submit the jar, and then input the entry class and then click the Submit button to submit the job

4. The job is done successfully, but I didn't find the output in the TaskManager or JobManager Logs on the UI.
```

I would ask where I can find the output

The word count application is:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.ExecutionEnvironment

import org.apache.flink.api.scala._

/**
  * Wordcount example
  */

object WordCount {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val data = List("hi", "how are you", "hi")

    val dataSet = env.fromCollection(data)

    val words = dataSet.flatMap(value => value.split("\\s+"))

    val mappedWords = words.map(value => (value, 1))

    val grouped = mappedWords.groupBy(0)

    val sum = grouped.sum(1)

    sum.collect().foreach(println)


  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the log directory of each taskmanager machine you should find both *.log and *.out files. Whatever your job has printed will go to the .out files. This is what is displayed in the "stdout" tab for each taskmanager in the web UI -- though if this file is very large, the browser may struggle to fetch and display it.

Update: Apparently the Flink's batch environment handles printing differently from the streaming one. When I use the CLI to submit this batch job, the output appears in the terminal, and not in the .out files as it would for a streaming job.

I suggest you change your example to do something like this at the end to collect the results in a file:

```
...
sum.writeAsText("/tmp/test")
env.execute()
```

Comment: Thanks @david-anderson.  I double check both the UI and log files as you said, and didn't find the output..